# I have video id more than 46,000 which will be searching with my database records (about 10,000). If exist then this id will be stored in a array

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, search

I have video id more than 46,000  which will be searching with my database records (about 10,000). If exist then this id will be stored in a array . I have created a php script to do that but it is take more than 50sec and with a high pressure on my laptop running WAMP. I think there are many algorithm on searching to do such work.
I want to know if there any alternative faster way to do that. My code is attached below.
Thanks

```
$query = "SELECT video_id,title FROM `all_videos`";
$res = mysql_query($query);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    $b = array_search($row[0], $arr);  // Searching video id from $arr - array..
    if ($b != '' or $b === 0) // Matching..
    {
        echo 'Match Found!! => ' . $row[0] . ' || ' . $row[1] . '<hr>';
        $del[$i] = $row[0];
        $i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a `where` clause on the query. `SELECT video_id,title FROM all_videos where video_id = ?`. Also update your driver to `mysqli` or `pdo`. If `$arr` has multiple ids in it use an `in`.

Comment: What is `$arr`?

Comment: Thanks for that. $arr is array , contained more than 46,000 multiple video ids

Comment: If you have all the `id`s from the db in an array already why do you need to `select` them? How are you getting that array, with a separate query?

Comment: My code is worked but It take much time & pressure on server. I know there are so many works to do as you see . I am thinking about another algorithm (ex- binary search) and also want to know if it possible to apply for this work.

Comment: from $_POST , inputted in textarea.

Comment: You are maxing out your resources because you are looping through 46,000 records and then scanning each row. Use mysql's functionality to scan and it will return only the relevant rows.

Comment: Code should go in the question. Use the `edit` option.

Comment: Actually my work on embed videos from a embed video provider site and I have added videos about 10,000. This website also provide deleted ids into txt file about 46,000 . I copy that and paste into text box , now this inputted value pass via post and explode it into **$arr** (this is the array). Now I have to check it with my database , if exist then this id will be stored in a array (Here- **$del**  ) for delete. Delete part will be later as for only checking, it hangs my laptop.

Comment: Problem solved !..My thinking of logic was another slow process , for now My main process is only 2 lines and time less than 12 sec.